# Allow certain IP addresses to SSH

Tags: ssh, centos7, firewalld

I want to allow only a few IP addresses for making SSH connection.
I'm using CentOS 7 with firewalld and OpenSSH SSH client.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I tried placing the IP's in the SSH config file: "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" with ListenAddress.

I also searched for commando's like:
firewall-cmd --remove-service=ssh
firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule="rule family="ipv4" source address="xx.xx.xx.xx" service name="ssh" accept"
I want to know for sure that it's works, because remove-service sounds scary.

Comment: With all due respect, please do research before making changes like this. ListenAddress has absolutely nothing to do with what you want to accomplish. As mentioned below, you need to research firewalls and iptables.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve by reading following:

- `man firewall-cmd` (firewall-cmd - firewalld command line client)
- `man iptables` (iptables/ip6tables — administration tool for IPv4/IPv6 packet filtering and NAT)

Comment: Did you consider using `Match` in `sshd_config` to achieve this?